# What does "You can run the command X with Y" mean?

Tags: key-bindings

I'm running `M-x man ...` and I'm getting this in my `*Messages*` buffer:

`` You can run the command `man' with m ``

What does it mean? It obviously doesn't run when I just press `m` and it doesn't run `man` when I do `M-x m` either.

I have looked in my config and there's nothing mentioning man there.

Comment: Hmm. It *should* mean that you can run it just by pressing `m`. This is clearly not a global binding, though, nor does it make a lot of sense in a buffer with normal editing functions. It might make sense in some special read-only buffers, however. In what context do you get this response?

Comment: Oooh. It makes sense now that you put it that way. I got that response when I had already opened a man buffer. And in the context of that buffer, pressing `m` does run `man`. It didn't when I went to the *Messages* buffer though... Obviously...

Comment: Okay, I added a brief answer just so the question wouldn't linger in the unanswered state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `m` key does indeed run the `man` command in the given context, which turned out to be a `Man-mode` buffer. Never forget that keybindings can be local! They can even vary within the same buffer, depending on character properties.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, so the answer does not just refer to a comment now.